# Picking the right MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

I am building a small smoke machine using a vape pen atomizer as a base and connecting a small aquarium air pump to force air past the heating element in the atomizer.

I want to be able to control the atomizer's heating element with an Arduino Micro (3.3V version running at 8 MHz) PWM output. For this, I figured I needed a MOSFET.

I am no electrical engineer and I have been reading up on the [characteristics of MOSFETS](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/application-note/AN11158.pdf). With this information I concluded I would need a N-channel enhancement MOSFET with a low VGs(th) so that I can control it with the 3.3V PWM ports, and a minimum ID of ~3A so that it can drive the heating element. I settled on the [IRFZ44N](https://components101.com/mosfets/irfz44n-datasheet-pinout-features), now the question is am I correct in this assumption? I am uncertain because these MOSFETs have so many characteristics that I believe I am missing something important.

Technical details:

- Everything is powered by a 1S 3.7V 4200 mAh Li-poly battery (26650 form factor)
- The heating element is a spiral with a resistance of 1.6 ohm running on 3.3-4.2V (based on battery charge) at 2.1-2.6A

Comment: Tip: have a look at BigClive's Youtube channel: https://www.youtube.com/user/bigclivedotcom he has made some Vaping-device teardown videos. I could not find any video where it is mentioned what MOSFETs are used in these devices though.

Comment: As Andy suggests, look for a MOSFET that specifies its Rds(on) at your gate drive voltage or lower. Otherwise the smoke will come from the MOSFET instead of the atomizer.

Comment: I think your pick is good. I think your load current of 2.6A max can be handled, because the Ron is around 14 mΩ max, which is laughably small compared with eg TP120 NPN BJT's Vce(sat) of around 1V at 2A. Let me do my always dodgy calculations: (1) MOSFET Ron * I max = 14mΩ x 2.6A < 50 mW, (2) BJT Vsat 1V * 2.6A = 2.6W.  I checked that for TP120 power NPN BJT, Vce(sat) = 2V at Ic = 3A. TP120 https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TIP120-D.PDF

Comment: @tlfong01 even the front page of the IRFZ44N data sheet states a max on resistance of 17.5 mΩ so where you got 14 from is odd. Anyway, with only 3.3 volts applied to the gate, the on-resistance is going to be off-the-scale (and I don't mean lower).

Comment: @Andy aka, my apologies for the mysterious number 14. I might have remembered wrongly another datasheet's parameter.  I did read your remark about "data sheet graphs don't even bother going down to show results at 3.3 volts". I tend to think that what is below 4.5V does not matter that much, because MOSFET's Ron of 10mΩ would still win NPN BJT by a big margin. I did once read MOSFET data sheets showing data below 3V, but I am not very sure. Let me try to search my old files and report back later. My apologies for any misunderstanding.

Comment: I was talking about this: (1) IRL540N: https://i.imgur.com/HKtldj7.jpg, (2) https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irl540npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153565fc2a62567. Ah, bed time. Call it a day, See you tomorrow. Cheers.

Comment: I also tested another low Vgs(th) MOSFET: (3) https://i.imgur.com/dTpPi5N.png. More references: 
Testing and comparing Low Vgs(th) Power MOSFETs:
(4) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=232753&hilit=IRL540N+tlfong01&start=125#p1432684
(5) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=232753&hilit=IRL540N+tlfong01&start=75#p1430914
(6) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=232753&hilit=IRL540N+tlfong01&start=125#p1433382.

Comment: Refs (6) CSD18511KCS N-Channel Low (Logic Level) Vgs(th) = 1.8V Power MOSFET - TI
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd18511kcs.pdf?ts=1597810464818&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FCSD18511KCS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an [IRL3803VPBF](https://www.digikey.ch/product-detail/en/infineon-technologies/IRL3803VPBF/IRL3803VPBF-ND/811249) can fit your needs. Contrary to the model you mention and in addition to Andy aka's comment, it has the following Ids versus Vgs relationship :

[image: Ids versus Vgs]

For the drain current you have in worst case (2.6 A) and the gate voltage you provide (3.3 V), the voltage drop between the drain and the source will be smaller than 0.1 V, the minimum that we can see in the [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/107886.pdf). That means that the current that goes through the transistor will not produce excessive heat and in the end, most of the energy provided by the battery will effectively reach your heating element.

Answer (score 2):

> *I settled on the IRFZ44N, now the question is am I correct in this
> assumption?*

The [IRFZ44N](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfz44npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b3a9f220d) is going to be a poor choice for this device: -

[image]

The data sheet graphs don't even bother going down to show results at 3.3 volts between gate and source because the gate threshold voltage might be as high as 4 volts and this is way beyond the logic level you are considering applying to control it.

Look for a MOSFET with a maximum drain-source voltage of around 15 to 20 volts is my advice - they are much more likely to be suited to your application because they will have naturally lower on-resistance and many will be suited for low level logic drive voltages.

Comment: I have selected the other answer as the correct answer because it explained why the one he suggested was better. However, your answer was very valuable for my understanding.

Comment: @Milan in doing so you are **implicitly** going against a site rule (that is for a question **not** to make shopping requests). If you are looking for shopping recommendations then this isn't the site to use. On the face of it you weren't making an **explicit** request but, in accepting that answer you are making an implicit request. Apart from that, the other answer was somewhat piggy-backing on the details in my answer and, if my answer wasn't there his answer (as it stands) would not be complete. Think about what I'm saying.

Answer (score 2):

I've made good experiences with IRLML6244 (20V Vds_max, 12V Vgs_max, 5A Id_max) and PMV37ENEA (60V Vds_max, 20V Vgs_max, 3,5A Id_max) N-Fets for direct drive by Microcontrollers. They both have a small VGS-Threshold-Voltage of roundabout 1-2V for switching on.

Nevertheless, the minimum RDSon is reached at 10V Vgs or so, so the maximum current may be limited due to your maximum control voltage of 3.3V and limited Charge/Discharge Current for the Mosfet.